# SQL query in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can we write this SQL in Rails3 .
tables : node, meta

```
select n.node_id
from node n
join meta m1 on m1.node_id = n.node_id 
            and m1.code = 'weight' and m1.value = '120'
join meta m2 on m2.node_id = n.node_id
            and m2.code = 'lower' and m2.value = '1'
join meta m3 on m3.node_id = n.node_id
            and m3.code = 'height' and m3.value = ''
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's better if you explain what you want to do, in english, referring to your rails schema, rather than ask people to reverse engineer sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord::Base#find_by_sql method to get query results.
Read more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql).